# Link in inline code not changing color when visited

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, dark-mode

In the screenshot below, both links have been visited, but the color of the second link still remains a darker blue.

[image]

I think this is fixed in light mode, but I couldn't really tell because my eyes were crying.

Comment: [A post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/image-processing-algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-recognition) to test on.

Comment: Workaround: [control the unvisited and visited colours yourself](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-can-i-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-colors-a/638257#638257) (I only override the visited colour, not the unvisited (only one line in Firefox' file */chrome/userContent.css*: `a:visited { color:OrangeRed!important; }`). I am never in doubt about it.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen So you say it comes from my system settings? So Stack Overflow doesn't change the link color itself?

Comment: No, I am not saying that (though it could be the case). I don't know if Stack Overflow overrides the link colours or not (for example, depending on dark mode).

Comment: Ask Ubuntu does override at least the unvisited colour. [Sample](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762541/ubuntu-16-04-ssh-sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation).